# Arrow function in Javascript Object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

```
let objNewWay = {
  width:400,
  height:300,
  area: () => this.width*this.height
};

console.log(objNewWay.area()); // NaN

let objOldWay = {
  width:400,
  height:300,
  area: function() {
    return this.width*this.height;
  }
};

console.log(objOldWay.area()); // 120000
```

I don't understand why the arrow function in Javascript object does not seems to work. If you look at the code above, the first console.log prints NaN, and the second prints the number as expected.

https://jsbin.com/pazazikayi/edit?js,console

Comment: Its called [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) not lamda

Comment: From _MDN_: ___Two factors influenced the introduction of arrow functions: shorter functions and non-binding of `this`.___

Comment: Thanks. I have changed the question from lambda to array function.

Comment: **arrow** function, not *array* function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) :

> An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax than a function
>   expression and **does not bind** its own **this**, **arguments**, **super**, or
>   **new.target**. These function expressions are best suited for non-method
>   functions, and they cannot be used as constructors.

You have to use the old way like you already showed

```
area: function() {
   return this.width*this.height;
}
```

if you still want to use the arrow function, you have to call the object itself

```js
let objNewWay = {
  width:400,
  height:300,
  area: ()=> objNewWay.width*objNewWay.height
};

console.log(objNewWay.area()); // NaN
```

Comment: Thanks. So what is the consideration of the design that makes the differences?

Comment: @ElgsQianChen Follow the link to the documenation - You will see *$No binding of this**

Comment: @ElgsQianChen Dont forget to tick the answer

Answer (score 1):

The [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) are not lambdas, and the way you use it will refer to a different scope from your object's.

For instance, from the console:

```
let theObj = {
    whereAmI: () => console.log(this)
}

theObj.whereAmI();

// Window...
```

If you want to use `this` keyword, use to the `area: function(){}` way.